# How do I update Drupal 8.2.3 REST configurations for an entity?

Tags: 8

According to the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview#practical), I need to update the REST configuration for each entity type. RESTUI seems not to work with 8.2.3, so I figure I'm supposed to update this by hand, for example in rest.resource.entity.node.yml.

I do that, and then I'm stuck. Where does this file go? Does it go in my code somewhere? Am I supposed to import it through Configuration Synchronization (admin/config/development/configuration/single/import)?

I did try to import using Config Synch, but I got the following error, which means nothing to a newbie like me: `An entity with this machine name already exists but the import did not specify a UUID.`

[image]

Sorry if this is already documented somewhere, but I can't find an explanation anywhere for how to update these settings, and they seem pretty important for using the REST services. I'm currently using the Features Module as a workaround but it's kind of an ugly approach for something that seems like it should be simple.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, you'll want to remove the imported configuration from the database and then reimport it with an included UUID - after which you can overwrite the config by re-importing it as many times as you like.

But first, when you upload a config, you should give it a more meaningful ID; rather than 'entity.node', you want something like 'my_config_for_this_thing'.

So in steps:

1. In your DB, find the config you uploaded (and see note about about the config ID):

   ```
   select name from config where name like '%entity.node%';
   ```
2. Copy the full name that matches your config.  It will be something like 'migrate_plus.migration.entity.node'.
3. Delete that row from the database

   ```
   delete from config where name = '*paste that name here*';
   ```
4. In your yml file, include a uuid. You can generate one locally or using a web tool such as https://www.uuidgenerator.net.  This will look something like

   ```
   id: some_meaningful_identifier
   label: 'A label to describe my config'
   status: true
   uuid: ac1d69cc-382f-49d2-921e-bb0673fd62ea
   ```
5. Clear your Drupal cache
6. Then re-import and you should be in better shape.